# Is it a good idea to cascade localization translation files?

Tags: localization, internationalization

I am structuring translation files for localization.  I would like to support country-specific cultures, such as "fr-CA" and "fr-BE".  I also know there are non-country-specific language codes that often correspond with these cultures -- in this example "fr".

I would like to limit as much translation duplication as possible, so the thought is France French would be stored in the "fr" file and contain every string, then each country-specific file would only include translation keys for those phrases or words that differ from the base "fr" file and essentially merge the translations together.

Is there value in this approach, or does it make more sense to simply duplicate the entirety of the base file into each country-specific culture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes perfect sense if the platform/programming environment you use supports cascading. Most platforms support. The translation process is a bit challenging. You have to instruct the translators to fill the translation first to fr and then only if the locale needs a different translation to add a locale-specific translation such as fr-FR.

Here is an article about [fallbacks](https://www.soluling.com/Help/Fallback.htm).

Comment: Thank you!  Translation management does seem like the most difficult part to manage, but we may be able to design an interface to make that easier.